# Mysql - PHP show data from one column over 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a moodle install but building a standalone report.

The fieldid has integers which relate to personnel info.

```
fieldid    information
   1        Job Title
   2        Payrol
   3        Dept
```

I would like three separate columns with the info.
It works fine within moodle using alias's then reference the alias for the column info.
But I can't get it to work in php.

```
From Moodle

JOIN prefix_user_info_data AS uid ON uid.userid = u.id
JOIN prefix_user_info_data AS uid2 ON uid2.userid = u.id
JOIN prefix_user_info_data AS uid3 ON uid3.userid = u.id
JOIN prefix_user_info_data AS uid4 ON uid4.userid = u.id

WHERE uid.fieldid = '13'
AND uid2.fieldid = '1'
AND uid3.fieldid = '3'
AND uid4.fieldid = '8'
```

Sharing the php and full code isn't going to help much, I only showed the relavant bits.  I've included the part of the php using the info.
The ['data'] columns is the one where the information is.
when I include AND uid2.fieldid = '1' it only shows department.
I would like another two columns for job title and payroll number.

```
$course = $_POST["course"];
$date= $_POST["date"];
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, data, name, statuscode, DATE_FORMAT       (FROM_UNIXTIME(timestart),'%d/%m/%y') AS timestart,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timefinish),'%d/%m/%y') AS timefinish


 FROM mdl_facetoface 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions ON       mdl_facetoface_sessions.facetoface=mdl_facetoface.id
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates  ON      mdl_facetoface_sessions.id=mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates.sessionid
 INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_signups  ON     mdl_facetoface_sessions.id=mdl_facetoface_signups.sessionid
 INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_facetoface_signups.userid=mdl_user.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_signups_status ON   mdl_facetoface_signups.id=mdl_facetoface_signups_status.signupid
 INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data  ON mdl_user_info_data.userid = mdl_user.id




 WHERE name LIKE '%".$course."%'
 AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid ='1'
 AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestart),'%d/%m/%y') LIKE '%".$date."%'
  AND firstname <> 'test'
 AND lastname <> 'test'
 AND statuscode ='70'
 AND statuscode<>'10'
 AND statuscode <>'20'
 AND statuscode <>'30'
 AND statuscode <>'40'
 AND statuscode <>'50'
 AND statuscode <>'60'
 AND statuscode <>'80'
 AND statuscode <>'90'
 AND statuscode <>'100'";

echo '<table width="90%">';

  echo '<td width="25%">'.'<h2>'.$row["firstname"].' '.$row["lastname"].'</h2>'.'</td><td width="25%">'.'<h2>'.$row["data"].'</h2>'.'</td><td width="20%"></td><td width="30%"></td>';

        }
      echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Your SQL looks somehow incomplete. Also, it could be useful to include the table structure (output of `DESC <tablename>`).

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote in PHP that is not working as expected?

Comment: there is nothing about php, only about sql

Comment: could you upload some sample data of what you want to get out of the database?

Comment: The personnel data is in one column so it comes through as; column 1= peoples names, column 2= job title, payrol number, department, so there is three entries per person. Ideally the data comes through as column 1 = persons name, column 2 = job title, column 3 = Dept etc..

Answer (score 0):

I finally got some time to spend on fixing this. As usual it was simple when I figured it out.
These are the bits I needed to change or add.

```
 SELECT  p.data AS pay, t.data AS title, d.data AS dept,

 FROM 
 INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data AS p ON p.userid = mdl_user.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data AS t ON t.userid = mdl_user.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data AS d ON d.userid = mdl_user.id

 WHERE  p.fieldid='3'
 AND t.fieldid='9'
 AND d.fieldid='1'

 <td width="20%"><h2>'.$row["title"].'</h2></td>
 <td width="20%"><h2>'.$row["dept"].'</h2></td>
 <td width="15%"><h2>'.$row["pay"].'</h2></td>
```

cheers for looking